# Retrieving the latest document in Elasticsearch takes a long time

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm having an Elasticsearch 7.2 index with currently around 3.5 billion documents. Most queries run without any issues, but for some reason, sorting by timestamp and retrieving the latest document is taking very long.

So this is the query:

```
{
  "query": { "match_all": {} },
  "size": 1,
  "sort": [{
      "@timestamp": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

This is my timestamp field mapping:

```
{
  "mapping": {
    "properties": {
      "@timestamp": {
        "type": "date"
      }
      // ....
    }
  }
}
```

And this is the my query profile:

```
{
  "took": 227405,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 4,
    "successful": 4,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": {
      "value": 10000,
      "relation": "gte"
    },
    "max_score": null,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "my-index",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "7726392481",
        "_score": null,
        "_source": {
          "@timestamp": "2019-07-08T13:11:21.500",
          // ...
        },
        "sort": [
          1562591481500
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "profile": {
    "shards": [
      {
        "id": "[sdKq0LgLRAqxbCjpAPKn_g][my-index][0]",
        "searches": [
          {
            "query": [
              {
                "type": "MatchAllDocsQuery",
                "description": "*:*",
                "time_in_nanos": 40925661356,
                "breakdown": {
                  "set_min_competitive_score_count": 0,
                  "match_count": 0,
                  "shallow_advance_count": 0,
                  "set_min_competitive_score": 0,
                  "next_doc": 40011007556,
                  "match": 0,
                  "next_doc_count": 913921033,
                  "score_count": 0,
                  "compute_max_score_count": 0,
                  "compute_max_score": 0,
                  "advance": 0,
                  "advance_count": 0,
                  "score": 0,
                  "build_scorer_count": 164,
                  "create_weight": 10615,
                  "shallow_advance": 0,
                  "create_weight_count": 1,
                  "build_scorer": 721987
                }
              }
            ],
            "rewrite_time": 6503,
            "collector": [
              {
                "name": "CancellableCollector",
                "reason": "search_cancelled",
                "time_in_nanos": 155966573371,
                "children": [
                  {
                    "name": "SimpleFieldCollector",
                    "reason": "search_top_hits",
                    "time_in_nanos": 78972338307
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
        "aggregations": []
      },
      {
        "id": "[sdKq0LgLRAqxbCjpAPKn_g][my-index][1]",
        "searches": [
          {
            "query": [
              {
                "type": "MatchAllDocsQuery",
                "description": "*:*",
                "time_in_nanos": 41782046319,
                "breakdown": {
                  "set_min_competitive_score_count": 0,
                  "match_count": 0,
                  "shallow_advance_count": 0,
                  "set_min_competitive_score": 0,
                  "next_doc": 40847593118,
                  "match": 0,
                  "next_doc_count": 933744955,
                  "score_count": 0,
                  "compute_max_score_count": 0,
                  "compute_max_score": 0,
                  "advance": 0,
                  "advance_count": 0,
                  "score": 0,
                  "build_scorer_count": 166,
                  "create_weight": 2479,
                  "shallow_advance": 0,
                  "create_weight_count": 1,
                  "build_scorer": 705600
                }
              }
            ],
            "rewrite_time": 4551,
            "collector": [
              {
                "name": "CancellableCollector",
                "reason": "search_cancelled",
                "time_in_nanos": 155800230172,
                "children": [
                  {
                    "name": "SimpleFieldCollector",
                    "reason": "search_top_hits",
                    "time_in_nanos": 78854977582
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
        "aggregations": []
      },
      {
        "id": "[yUQy-JyKQxigULToVE2VSA][my-index][2]",
        "searches": [
          {
            "query": [
              {
                "type": "MatchAllDocsQuery",
                "description": "*:*",
                "time_in_nanos": 41297021897,
                "breakdown": {
                  "set_min_competitive_score_count": 0,
                  "match_count": 0,
                  "shallow_advance_count": 0,
                  "set_min_competitive_score": 0,
                  "next_doc": 40377677681,
                  "match": 0,
                  "next_doc_count": 918611705,
                  "score_count": 0,
                  "compute_max_score_count": 0,
                  "compute_max_score": 0,
                  "advance": 0,
                  "advance_count": 0,
                  "score": 0,
                  "build_scorer_count": 166,
                  "create_weight": 2962,
                  "shallow_advance": 0,
                  "create_weight_count": 1,
                  "build_scorer": 729382
                }
              }
            ],
            "rewrite_time": 3312,
            "collector": [
              {
                "name": "CancellableCollector",
                "reason": "search_cancelled",
                "time_in_nanos": 163874355059,
                "children": [
                  {
                    "name": "SimpleFieldCollector",
                    "reason": "search_top_hits",
                    "time_in_nanos": 87826427892
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
        "aggregations": []
      },
      {
        "id": "[yUQy-JyKQxigULToVE2VSA][my-index][3]",
        "searches": [
          {
            "query": [
              {
                "type": "MatchAllDocsQuery",
                "description": "*:*",
                "time_in_nanos": 41461752119,
                "breakdown": {
                  "set_min_competitive_score_count": 0,
                  "match_count": 0,
                  "shallow_advance_count": 0,
                  "set_min_competitive_score": 0,
                  "next_doc": 40536907380,
                  "match": 0,
                  "next_doc_count": 924035258,
                  "score_count": 0,
                  "compute_max_score_count": 0,
                  "compute_max_score": 0,
                  "advance": 0,
                  "advance_count": 0,
                  "score": 0,
                  "build_scorer_count": 178,
                  "create_weight": 2959,
                  "shallow_advance": 0,
                  "create_weight_count": 1,
                  "build_scorer": 806343
                }
              }
            ],
            "rewrite_time": 3316,
            "collector": [
              {
                "name": "CancellableCollector",
                "reason": "search_cancelled",
                "time_in_nanos": 163785688664,
                "children": [
                  {
                    "name": "SimpleFieldCollector",
                    "reason": "search_top_hits",
                    "time_in_nanos": 87831077038
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
        "aggregations": []
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

It spends a lot of time on `next_doc` with a `next_doc_count` of 933,744,955. However as the `@timestamp` field is indexed, why does it need to go through all the documents to sort them and return the latest one?

**Edit:**

Those are my index stats:

```
{
  "_shards": {
    "total": 4,
    "successful": 4,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "stats": {
    "uuid": "ub-FElCTTsOAihR0aoNlPw",
    "primaries": {
      "docs": {
        "count": 3467397640,
        "deleted": 234593502
      },
      "store": {
        "size_in_bytes": 1087736351822
      },
      "indexing": {
        "index_total": 204398539,
        "index_time_in_millis": 80325395,
        "index_current": 0,
        "index_failed": 0,
        "delete_total": 0,
        "delete_time_in_millis": 0,
        "delete_current": 0,
        "noop_update_total": 0,
        "is_throttled": false,
        "throttle_time_in_millis": 0
      },
      "get": {
        "total": 0,
        "time_in_millis": 0,
        "exists_total": 0,
        "exists_time_in_millis": 0,
        "missing_total": 0,
        "missing_time_in_millis": 0,
        "current": 0
      },
      "search": {
        "open_contexts": 0,
        "query_total": 1524,
        "query_time_in_millis": 14514546,
        "query_current": 0,
        "fetch_total": 1018,
        "fetch_time_in_millis": 171319,
        "fetch_current": 0,
        "scroll_total": 0,
        "scroll_time_in_millis": 0,
        "scroll_current": 0,
        "suggest_total": 0,
        "suggest_time_in_millis": 0,
        "suggest_current": 0
      },
      "merges": {
        "current": 0,
        "current_docs": 0,
        "current_size_in_bytes": 0,
        "total": 192984,
        "total_time_in_millis": 87010422,
        "total_docs": 1248881022,
        "total_size_in_bytes": 394269971046,
        "total_stopped_time_in_millis": 0,
        "total_throttled_time_in_millis": 35698367,
        "total_auto_throttle_in_bytes": 20971520
      },
      "refresh": {
        "total": 377992,
        "total_time_in_millis": 38968248,
        "external_total": 377333,
        "external_total_time_in_millis": 40675901,
        "listeners": 0
      },
      "flush": {
        "total": 383,
        "periodic": 155,
        "total_time_in_millis": 695510
      },
      "warmer": {
        "current": 0,
        "total": 377329,
        "total_time_in_millis": 18259
      },
      "query_cache": {
        "memory_size_in_bytes": 0,
        "total_count": 0,
        "hit_count": 0,
        "miss_count": 0,
        "cache_size": 0,
        "cache_count": 0,
        "evictions": 0
      },
      "fielddata": {
        "memory_size_in_bytes": 17973802844,
        "evictions": 0
      },
      "completion": {
        "size_in_bytes": 0
      },
      "segments": {
        "count": 319,
        "memory_in_bytes": 1174162151,
        "terms_memory_in_bytes": 942165919,
        "stored_fields_memory_in_bytes": 126159816,
        "term_vectors_memory_in_bytes": 0,
        "norms_memory_in_bytes": 192640,
        "points_memory_in_bytes": 102814280,
        "doc_values_memory_in_bytes": 2829496,
        "index_writer_memory_in_bytes": 12899088,
        "version_map_memory_in_bytes": 29403,
        "fixed_bit_set_memory_in_bytes": 0,
        "max_unsafe_auto_id_timestamp": -1,
        "file_sizes": {}
      },
      "translog": {
        "operations": 3766740,
        "size_in_bytes": 2307404347,
        "uncommitted_operations": 2893204,
        "uncommitted_size_in_bytes": 1782804035,
        "earliest_last_modified_age": 0
      },
      "request_cache": {
        "memory_size_in_bytes": 0,
        "evictions": 0,
        "hit_count": 0,
        "miss_count": 268
      },
      "recovery": {
        "current_as_source": 0,
        "current_as_target": 0,
        "throttle_time_in_millis": 17024187
      }
    },
    "total": {
      "docs": {
        "count": 3467397640,
        "deleted": 234593502
      },
      "store": {
        "size_in_bytes": 1087736351822
      },
      "indexing": {
        "index_total": 204398539,
        "index_time_in_millis": 80325395,
        "index_current": 0,
        "index_failed": 0,
        "delete_total": 0,
        "delete_time_in_millis": 0,
        "delete_current": 0,
        "noop_update_total": 0,
        "is_throttled": false,
        "throttle_time_in_millis": 0
      },
      "get": {
        "total": 0,
        "time_in_millis": 0,
        "exists_total": 0,
        "exists_time_in_millis": 0,
        "missing_total": 0,
        "missing_time_in_millis": 0,
        "current": 0
      },
      "search": {
        "open_contexts": 0,
        "query_total": 1524,
        "query_time_in_millis": 14514546,
        "query_current": 0,
        "fetch_total": 1018,
        "fetch_time_in_millis": 171319,
        "fetch_current": 0,
        "scroll_total": 0,
        "scroll_time_in_millis": 0,
        "scroll_current": 0,
        "suggest_total": 0,
        "suggest_time_in_millis": 0,
        "suggest_current": 0
      },
      "merges": {
        "current": 0,
        "current_docs": 0,
        "current_size_in_bytes": 0,
        "total": 192984,
        "total_time_in_millis": 87010422,
        "total_docs": 1248881022,
        "total_size_in_bytes": 394269971046,
        "total_stopped_time_in_millis": 0,
        "total_throttled_time_in_millis": 35698367,
        "total_auto_throttle_in_bytes": 20971520
      },
      "refresh": {
        "total": 377992,
        "total_time_in_millis": 38968248,
        "external_total": 377333,
        "external_total_time_in_millis": 40675901,
        "listeners": 0
      },
      "flush": {
        "total": 383,
        "periodic": 155,
        "total_time_in_millis": 695510
      },
      "warmer": {
        "current": 0,
        "total": 377329,
        "total_time_in_millis": 18259
      },
      "query_cache": {
        "memory_size_in_bytes": 0,
        "total_count": 0,
        "hit_count": 0,
        "miss_count": 0,
        "cache_size": 0,
        "cache_count": 0,
        "evictions": 0
      },
      "fielddata": {
        "memory_size_in_bytes": 17973802844,
        "evictions": 0
      },
      "completion": {
        "size_in_bytes": 0
      },
      "segments": {
        "count": 319,
        "memory_in_bytes": 1174162151,
        "terms_memory_in_bytes": 942165919,
        "stored_fields_memory_in_bytes": 126159816,
        "term_vectors_memory_in_bytes": 0,
        "norms_memory_in_bytes": 192640,
        "points_memory_in_bytes": 102814280,
        "doc_values_memory_in_bytes": 2829496,
        "index_writer_memory_in_bytes": 12899088,
        "version_map_memory_in_bytes": 29403,
        "fixed_bit_set_memory_in_bytes": 0,
        "max_unsafe_auto_id_timestamp": -1,
        "file_sizes": {}
      },
      "translog": {
        "operations": 3766740,
        "size_in_bytes": 2307404347,
        "uncommitted_operations": 2893204,
        "uncommitted_size_in_bytes": 1782804035,
        "earliest_last_modified_age": 0
      },
      "request_cache": {
        "memory_size_in_bytes": 0,
        "evictions": 0,
        "hit_count": 0,
        "miss_count": 268
      },
      "recovery": {
        "current_as_source": 0,
        "current_as_target": 0,
        "throttle_time_in_millis": 17024187
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: how many shards and documents per index?

Comment: The index has 4 shards and 3.5 billion documents

Comment: and size of the primary shard, sorry forgot to ask?

Comment: It's about 1 TB in size. I've edited my question and added the index stats.

Answer (score 1):

Recommended shard size is `10-40GB`, and you have around `250GB`. Also, looks like you have many deleted docs, it's because you are overriding documents with same `_id`. They are marked as deleted, but they are still consuming RAM and are involved in operations - [More info](https://www.elastic.co/blog/lucenes-handling-of-deleted-documents)

Sorting is slow because it uninverts the inverted indices in `Lucene`. Option is to eagerly preload fielddata - [More info](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/preload-fielddata.html), and you should use `doc_value` on `@timestamp` field - [More info](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/doc-values.html).

One more option is, if you always sort by some field (e.g. by `timestamp desc`), you can sort index and tell `ES` how to order the documents on disk. [Check this](https://www.elastic.co/blog/index-sorting-elasticsearch-6-0).

Hope it will help.

Comment: Quite some useful resources, I'll have a look into those. Thanks!

Comment: Okay so I've re-indexed my whole index using 80 shards now instead of 4. There are also no more deleted docs around as they've got cleaned up on this process. The `doc_values` are enabled on the `@timestamp` field (as they default to `true`). This improved the speed a bit (up to 11 seconds), but it's still kinda slow.

Comment: On 4. Thought the sharding itself might increase performance, but I guess Elasticsearch has to go through all docs nonetheless. Which is kind of weird for indexed data.

Comment: yes, it’s searching on 20 shards sequentially per mode. How about reducing your index site, maybe to go on daily/monthly indices if dara is in time series, or by some other parameter? Do you have 3 replicas and turned od adaptive search (to search on replica also, not only on primary shards?) How big is your heap size? It is tricky to have such big index on only 4 nodes although..

Comment: Heap is 16 GB per node. How many nodes and what heap size would you recommend for such an index?

Comment: you can increase heap to max 32gb, but if you have 64gb ram, because rest of it is used for filesystem. Each search request will touch a copy of every shard in the index, which isn't a problem when the shards are spread across several nodes. Contention arises and performance decreases when the shards are competing for the same hardware resources. There is no silver bullet solution